# Tree component click event

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am using **tree component** along with **input component** as shown in below image.[image]

Here if i select **child element**(i,e Angular JS).That child element is selected and displayed on the input field as shown in below image.
[image]

**Here the issue is:** 
When i enter the input field then only the **tree** appears,
but when i click outside the **tree** the **tree** should disappear.how to do this? I need similar actions of **autocomplete** component.

Here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-yq8ehd?file=app/chips-autocomplete-example.html) link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the host listener to check if the mouse click is happening on the deired element, then change the status of showDropDown accordingly.
For Ex:

```
  showDropDown = false;
  @HostListener('click', [`$event`]) 
  onClick(event: MouseEvent){
    this.showDropDown = event.target['tagName'].match('MAT-TREE-NODE') || event.target['tagName'].match('INPUT') ? true : false;
  }
```

For Autocomplete like feature:
Check this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-h8zdkh-6z633t?file=app%2Fchips-autocomplete-example.ts) post.

Comment: Previously i tried this `(blur)="showDropDown = false"`. It's working fine but i am unable select the child element or anything from tree component.

Comment: On clicking outside the tree is disappearing fine, but i am unable select anything from the tree.

Comment: what do you mean by you are unable to select anything for tree? On clicking AngularJS, you are able to select AngularJs

Comment: I am unable to select anything from the tree.On clicking above the tree the tree is disappearing.

Comment: If possible,please  check the issue in **stackblitz**  link.

Comment: i have looked into stackblitz. On clicking tree component, you want that tree component to be select for input element. For Ex: On clicking Web technology, it should appear in the input element?

Comment: Ya you are right!. But if click input field and clicked outside without selecting anything from tree then the should disappear. And also if i select child element **HTML5** (not the parent **Web Technologies**.)the selected item as to be displayed in input field.

Comment: I need its working like autocomplete component, Is it possible?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/179885/discussion-between-prashanth-gh-and-shadab-faiz).